# Release APK seems to break Firebase functionality

Tags: android, firebase, proguard

I've been working on a Firebase-based social app for a while. The app was coming along fine, when I noticed everybody (except for me) kept getting inexplicable crashes. I assumed it was because the app was built around open source code, so I started anew from scratch. Again, the app was coming along fine, but as soon as I published it, similar inexplicable crashes started occuring. At this point I realised the crashes only occured in the release APK. As far as I can see, all of these crashes are related to Firebase. Most of them are `NullPointerExceptions` where some data is Null in the release APK, but not Null in the test version with the exact same use case.

I managed to solve one of these mysterious crashes by correctly implementing [multidex](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html) (I didn't implement this correctly before and I think this caused one of the problems). Problems still remain though. I've completely turned of ProGuard, because I suspect that may be one of the problems. ProGuard was disabled before, but now I added these lines, just to be sure:

```
-dontoptimize
-dontshrink
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-dontpreverify
-verbose
```

Still crashes.

This is becoming a bit of a problem. What could possibly solve this problem?

Here's my Build.gradle.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "app.id"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 16
        versionName "0.0.16"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        renderscriptTargetApi 24
        renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.1'

    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.0.1'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:2.0.1'
    [loads more dependencies]
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.6.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.jakewharton.butterknife'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Are the nullpointerexceptions related to FirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() ?

Comment: Post your logcat

Comment: @MartinDeSimone I don't think they're related to FirebaseAuth, since I can view my own feed fine. Something's up with Auth though, since I need to clear data to log out (removing the app isn't enough apparently). Currently forcing a logcat, but the result is Firebase entries are empty whereas they shouldn't be, crashing everyone's app.

Comment: Not a logCat, but here's a demonstration of the error: https://i.imgur.com/N8N4X8F.jpg. Item #1 is posted with the debug version. As you can see, it has beerId (which is vital, the app requires it) and image. Item #2 suddenly has placeId (which it wasn't supposed to have) and misses the two vital nodes. Both entries were made by repeating the same steps, once in debug and once in release.

Comment: No code and no full stack trace.  How are we supposed to help?

Comment: This may not be the cause of your problem, but you should not list `com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.1` as a dependency.  Doing so brings in **ALL** of the Google Play APIs.  This makes your APK larger, increases build time, and often is the cause for needing Multidex.  Better to selectively include only the APIs you need as described in Table 1 of the [Setup Guide](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup).

Comment: Also, does your app's initialization code [check that a compatible version of Google Play services](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup#ensure_devices_have_the_google_play_services_apk) is installed on the device?  Failure to do so will cause errors when users run the app on devices with old versions of Google Play services.

Comment: @GabeSechan because it's not about the crashes per se. I can just catch the errors and it won't crash anymore. For example, this code would crash: `if (obj.getBrewery().getName()!=null)`, because `getBrewery()` would be null in the release version only.

Comment: @BobSnyder Thanks, that makes sense. I'm currently trying to get rid of mutidex alltogether. I'll let you know how that works out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has gone away on a fresh project. Here's the things I've done to avoid this.

- Switched to Android Studio 3.0 (Canary 7), including the new build tools
- Switched to Kotlin as my main project language
- Made sure my project's build.gradle gave no error notifications about different versions (using the project files view). Firebase UI caused one of these errors.
- Avoided MultiDex alltogether

Either one of these may have solved the problem. I'm not sure how long I can avoid using multidex, but I'll update this answer if I find out MultiDex is the problem and / or find an alternative solution.